# Unrecognized option "enabled" under "lexik_jwt_authentication.api_platform"

Tags: symfony, platform, lexikjwtauthbundle

I've got a problem while an initialization of a new symfony project. It seems to show a conflict of something else between api-plaform and the lexik jwt bundle.

Ok first I'm setting up a new project with that command:

```
symfony new <my-project>  ( or composer create command )
```

Then I install api-plaform:

```
composer require api
```

I finally set up lexik :

```
composer require composer require lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle
```

Unfortunately, I always got this error while cache cleaning:

> In ArrayNode.php line 327:
> !!
> !!    Unrecognized option "enabled" under
> "lexik_jwt_authentication.api_platform". Available options are
> "check_path", "password_path", "username_path".

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.10",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.16",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.18",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.3",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.23",
        "symfony/asset": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I can't explain this dysfuntion...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the fix here :

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/1152.

We need to enable sodium extension in php.ini file.

lcobucci/jwt 5.0.0 requires this.